# how to encrypt emails in mysql database but still be able to query them?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

I want to store the email addresses of users in a MySQL database using encryption to ensure that they won't be made public if the database gets compromised. I believe if I encrypt them with mysql's [`AES_ENCRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) function I can not create an index in an `INNODB` table because I have to use a `BLOB` datatype. If the table gets very large selects it will take a long time.

What is the best solution for securing email address but still being able to query them fast and preserve them as unique values in the column?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a user registers on your site, use AES_ENCRYPT() to encrypt the email.

```
INSERT into users (email) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('someemail@example.com', 'aeskey'));
```

When you query your database, you can call the AES_DECRYPT() function like this:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(email, 'aeskey') from users;
```

Comment: So basicly I can't create a unique index the email address column if I want to use encryption?

Comment: I believe that you shouldn't have conflicting AES encrypted values unless another user attempts to use the same email when registering. You can check that emails are unique by querying your database when a user registers.

A helpful link about AES Encryption and MySQL: http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/

Comment: I'll try to use a text column type, I enforce end to end utf-8 so it should be ok. If the whole server is compromised and not just the db then the hacker can grab the encryption key and decrypt the email addresses in the db.

Comment: @bshack, yes if both the key and the message are intercepted then the game is over, however you can have db server and application server on different boxes for yet another layer of security.

Comment: and then you have to store the key on your server anyway which, if your system and application is hacked, will be open to the hacker regardless.

Comment: @JM4, Not necessarily. If you have a server architecture that separates the application and database, this would be a more secure approach. In truth, anything can be cracked given the correct amount  of resources and time.

Answer (score 4):

If you hash the addresses with SHA-256 or something similar, you can still index your tables, you can still do fast address lookups (when a user searches for example@example.com, you'll just hash the input and select matching hashes in the tables).

[ssh](http://openssh.org) uses a [very similar](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen) hashing trick. (Look for the `-H` option in that manpage for details.)

Comment: I think if I do this method I can not un encrypt the email addresses and use them later to email the users if needed.

Comment: @bshack, any technique you may use that would allow you to retrieve the email addresses out of the database could also be used by an attacker who gets the database contents. Your only real protection at that point would be a key hard coded in your application, as @pcmantinker has suggested, but someone who gets a database dump frequently can get the program binary as well. (Not always, but relying on a key embedded in your code is pretty flimsy. :)

Comment: You could hash the email address for fast searching, and in a different column, or table, have the encrypted value. I would put it into a separate table, so you can put it on a different partition if needed.

Comment: Hashing, as @sarnold suggested, would be a good solution if you don't need explicit access to the emails in your database. I've used software that hashes passwords and compares a hashed value of the user's input with that from the database. It really depends on your purpose with retrieving emails though.

Comment: You could also hash the encrypted email instead of hash (plain) email...

Answer (score 0):

AES_DECRYPT(email, 'secretkey') and AES_ENCRYPT(email, 'secretkey') is optimal solution,

I am not 100% sure about beeing unique after encryption but theory said if email is unique encription should be unique

Comment: Can AES encrypted data be stored in a column type that can have an innodb column index on it?